# Magento 2 How to navigate to product page by make and model number

Tags: magento2, category-navigation

How to navigate to the product page by manufacturer and model number for example in my site I created category led tv parts >>led tv power supply. so when customer click led tv power supply I want the customer to select the manufacturer then when the customer selects the manufacturer I want the customer to select a model number when the customer selects the model number it should take the customer to the specific product for that make and model number. I hope someone can point me in the right direction your help would be really appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom solution for this functionality. However, if you are looking for any ready made extensions then there are so many options available in the market.

I have used Amasty Part Finder extension in one of my projects recently and its really great. Their support is also awesome. You may check it at

> https://amasty.com/product-parts-finder-for-magento-2.html

Thanks,